# DROP DOWN BOX is getting reset to the first value after clicking on SUBMIT or REFRESH button

Tags: php, html

I have a form with one drop down box(X) and one text box(Y). After selecting a value in X drop down box (For example: x2) and entering a value in the Y text box, when
**I click on the SUBMIT button, the value in the drop down box is getting reset to the First value(x1)**.I notice this same behavior, when I click on the refresh button.
But this is not the case with text box Y. can anyone help me with a sample piece of code. Or please tell me where I am going wrong and what I need to change.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>history plugin demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $x = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['X'] ) ? $_REQUEST['X'] : null );
        $y = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['Y'] ) ? $_REQUEST['Y'] : null );

    ?>
        Ajax load<BR>
            <form id="myForm" action='fields.php' method='GET' rel="history">
                X <BR>
                <select name="X"  value="<?=$x;?>">
                <option value="x1">x1</option>
                <option value="x2">x2</option>
                </select><BR> <BR>
                Y <BR>
                <input type="text" name="Y"  value="<?=$y;?>"> <BR> <BR>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Search" align="centre"/>
            </form>

            <!--other part of code!-->
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also add a `selected` attribute to the `option` that should be selected

```
<option value="x1" <?= ($x === 'x1' ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?> >x1</option>
<option value="x1" <?= ($x === 'x2' ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?> >x1</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select` html element doesn't have a value attribute, instead you set the selected attribute on the option elements:

```
<select name="X">
    <option value="x1"<?= $_REQUEST["X"]=="x1"?" selected='selected'":"" ?>>x1</option>
    <option value="x2"<?= $_REQUEST["X"]=="x2"?" selected='selected'":"" ?>>x2</option>
```